# Stopping jquery click event when an <a> tag is clicked

Tags: jquery, events, suppress

I am displaying record information in a table.  Based on user rights, I am adding a class to certain of the `<td>` elements that allows them to launch an on the fly editor.  This all works great until I have a `<td>` element that displays an `<a>` tag inside od it.

How do I suppress the `<td>` elements click handler if I click in the `<a>` element? I still want it to fire if I click in the `<td>` element, but outside the `<a>` element.

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: Add a call to stopPropagation on the click of the a tags.

Comment: @taplar - There is no event for the <a> tag, only the <td> tag

Comment: There is a click event for the a tag.  You can bind to it and do the stopPropagation there.

Comment: @Taplar - Ah!  Didn't think about binding the click event of the <a. tags.  Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Taplar pointed me to add a handler to the anchor tag and then stop propagation.  Works as needed.  If i click the anchor itself, only the link opens, if I click outside the anchor tag, but still within the table cell, the click event of the table cell fires.

Comment: Make sure to show some related code to avoid peeps potentially downvoting ya, :)